# Draw a rectangle to given Venn Diagram

Tags: venn-diagrams

Question: How can i draw a rectangle box which covers this figure?

Codes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

% Definition of circles
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(0:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}

\colorlet{circle edge}{blue!50}
\colorlet{circle area}{blue!20}

\tikzset{filled/.style={fill=circle area, draw=circle edge, thick},
    outline/.style={draw=circle edge, thick}}
% Set A or B
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[filled] \firstcircle node {$A$}
                  \secondcircle node {$B$};
    \node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north) {$A \cup B$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(from www.texample.net)

[image: Venn diagram]

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is to use the bounding box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

% Definition of circles
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(0:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}

\colorlet{circle edge}{blue!50} \colorlet{circle area}{blue!20}

\tikzset{filled/.style={fill=circle area, draw=circle edge, thick},
    outline/.style={draw=circle edge, thick}}
% Set A or B
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[filled] \firstcircle node {$A$}
               \secondcircle node {$B$};
 \node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north) {$A \cup B$};
 \draw (current bounding box.north west) rectangle
       (current bounding box.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you need a somewhat larger box (this need not be the most elegant solution, but it works):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

% Definition of circles
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(0:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}

\colorlet{circle edge}{blue!50} \colorlet{circle area}{blue!20}

\tikzset{filled/.style={fill=circle area, draw=circle edge, thick},
    outline/.style={draw=circle edge, thick}}
% Set A or B
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[filled] \firstcircle node {$A$}
               \secondcircle node {$B$};
 \node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north) {$A \cup B$};
 \draw ($(current bounding box.north west)+(-1,1)$) 
       node [below right] {$U$}
       rectangle ($(current bounding box.south east)+(1,-1)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: how may i increase the size of rectangle?

Comment: @snehal   I added a second version with a distance of 1 cm in each direction.

Comment: Just to let you know, seems the OP also wanted a label in the rectangle (see comments on my answer).

Comment: @Torbjørn T. Thanks for the hint, I added it to the second example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} and just simply add the option

```
[show background rectangle]
```

right after \begin{tikzpicture}

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach using the `fit` library.

Note, as egreg mentions in a comment, that in this particular case there is little point in defining macros for `\firstcircle` and `\secondcircle`, because you only use them once. If your actual document has more circles, that's another thing. Note also, that using `\newcommand` is in general preferred over `\def`, as it will not overwrite existing macros, but throw an error if the macro is already used for something.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\colorlet{circle edge}{blue!50}
\colorlet{circle area}{blue!20}

\tikzset{
  filled/.style={fill=circle area, draw=circle edge, thick},
  outline/.style={draw=circle edge, thick}
}
\begin{document}
% Set A or B
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[filled] (0,0) circle[radius=1.5cm] node {$A$}
               (0:2cm) circle[radius=1.5cm] node {$B$};
  \node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north) {$A \cup B$};

  % draw frame
  \node [draw,fit=(current bounding box),inner sep=3mm] (frame) {}; % modify inner sep to adjust gap from circles to frame

  % add label
  \node [below right] at (frame.north west) {$U$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Even if they're in the example code in texexample,, I don't think that `\firstcircle` and `\secondcircle` are a good idea.

Comment: @egreg In what sense? For this example it's not much point to use macros, sure, but the original example had more diagrams, and in some cases the same circle was used more than once in the same diagram (for clipping and drawing).

Comment: One small question i wanna lable that rectagnle as U(universal set).

Comment: Exactly: here they serve no purpose. And using `\def` is another bad idea (which you fixed).

Comment: @egreg I'll say something about it when I edit.

Comment: @snehal Where do you want that label? You can use the same technique you used to add the `A \cup B` node.

Comment: Sir i would like to lable at north-west corner of rectangle

Comment: @snehal Updated answer.