# Drawing Venn Diagrams

Tags: venn-diagrams

[image]

I don't know how to draw in Latex. Maybe someone has an idea how to make the diagram in the picture? Many thanks!

So here is my try:

```
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(0:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[filled] \firstcircle node {$n_{ij}$}
                  \secondcircle node {};
    \node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north) {$t_i,  t_j $};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Do someone know how to write $t_i$ on the left side and $t_j$ on the right side?

Comment: see http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/venn-diagram/. welcome to site!

Comment: How do I write letters inside or outside the diagram?

Comment: similarly as inside. you only need to define its definition. please, provide what you try so far. in given link you have good tart to compose your MWE (Minimal Working Example). From it to your desired result we can easy help you. Without it this is "do-it-for-me" question which is not likely to be answered (soon).

Comment: well, given link show `tikz` solution. beside it exist solution with other packages, like pstrick etc. Your question is not very clear about this. For `tikz` existe exist good manual, where are also examples for Wenn diagrams.

Comment: I will try to post a version of the code, but since I am new it will take me some time to understand how it works. I would be then glad to discuss it since I am afraid I will not manage to do it as it is in the picture. Thanks again

Comment: also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366945/draw-a-rectangle-to-given-venn-diagram?rq=1. it is very close what you like.

Answer (score 3):

With pure `tikz`, based on example of [venn-diagram](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/venn-diagram/)

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=1mm, fill,
              node contents={}}
                        ]
\def\firstcircle{(-1.2,0) coordinate (a) circle (2cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(1.2,0) coordinate (b)  circle (2cm)}
    \begin{scope}
\clip \secondcircle;
\fill[cyan] \firstcircle;
    \end{scope}
\draw \firstcircle  node[dot,label=$n_{ij}$];
\draw \secondcircle;
\node (c) [above] at (current bounding box.north -| a) {$t_i$};
\node at (c -| b) {$t_j$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much also for your solution. It looks good!

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple with the `venndiagram` package:

```
    \documentclass[svgnames]{article}

    \usepackage{venndiagram}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[labelA=, labelB=, shade =Gainsboro!65!Lavender!30]%
    \fillACapB
    \setpostvennhook
    {%
      \draw (labelA) ++(150:4ex) node{$ t_i $};
      \draw (labelA) ++(-105:8ex) node{$\scriptstyle\bullet$} ++(0,0) node[above]{$n_{i j} $};
     \draw (labelB) ++(20:5ex) node{$t_j$};;
        }%
    \end{venndiagram2sets}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it is very beautiful! However is there the option to put away the rectangle around?

Comment: @flos: I'm sure it's possible, but I'll have to look at the package code tomorrow – I must say I know `pstricks` better than TiKZ.